# .options[e.selectedIndex].innerHTML Not grabbing value

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with a select field with the id of to. I want to grab the selected value inside a javascript function. The first time I run this function it does not grab the selected value, but the second time I run the function it grabs the function. I have tried .text, this did not work. Thank you very much for your help.

```
var e = document.getElementById("to");
var str = e.options[e.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
```

Comment: Show more code since .text should work.

Comment: The value of an `<option>` is not necessarily equal to its innerHTMl (nor its innerText). If you just want to get the selected value, use `e.value`.

Answer (score 1):

So the first time you run it, are you running it before the element is rendered? If so you have to wait for document.ready or page load event.

Working example getting both text and value of a select element

**HTML**

```
<select id="foo">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
<button id="bar">Console it</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function getText() {
    var sel = document.getElementById("foo");        
    var option = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex];
    //assuming that there is always a selection
    var text = option.text;
    var value = option.value;
    console.log(text, value);
}

document.getElementById("bar").onclick = getText;

getText();
```

​

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dVR48/) In the fiddle, you can see that it is running onload when it tries to read the value.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting it in the onReady function.. maybe the JS is running before the page is fully loaded? If you're using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert($("#to option:selected").text());
)};
```